# Use ImageMagick compare command with image stream in python

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand

Background: I'm doing some image comparison using imagemagick's command line utility like so -

```
 `subprocess.call('compare -metric PHASH {0} {1} NULL:'.format(img1,img2))`
```

Where img1 and img2 are images from a remote url

```
response = requests.get('http://remoteimage/image.jpg',stream=True)
img1 = Image.open(cStringIO.StringIO(response.content))
```

This obviously doesn't work because i'm not writing the image to the disk - it's still in memory. Is there a way to run the compare command with the in memory Image object? Is there better ways of doing this than running the command line call - perhaps with Wand or another imagemagick to python lib.

Comment: Yes, there are better ways to do this with a Python ImageMagick lib. Pick one, try to write the code, and if you get stuck somewhere, you'll have a great StackOverflow question. But right now, there's really nothing more to say than that one line.

Comment: As a side note, using a command line instead of a list of arguments in a `subprocess` call without `shell=True` is very bad anywhere but Windows, and even on Windows it means you have to be careful about quoting your arguments properly, which you're not doing. Think about what your command line would look like if `img1` were `'spam eggs.jpg'`.

Comment: As an alternative, while there's no way to give a buffer in memory to an external program, there are ways to give them a pipe. Many programs can read input off `stdin`, which is easy to do with `subprocess`. A few can read input off any arbitrary fd, which is harder to do but still possible. Alternatively, is storing a temporary file (e.g., with `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile`) really a problem? It may never even make it out of the disk cache… But, all that being said, it's still better to do it within Python.